# Laravel Eloquent - Find all records from a given month

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following route.

```
Route::get('/blog/{search}/{slug}', array(
    'as' => 'public-blog-filter',
    function ($search, $slug) {

      if($search == 'search' ) {
        $search = 'title';
      } elseif($search == 'category') {
        $search = 'blog_category_id';
      } elseif($search == 'archives') {
        $search = 'published_at';
      }

      //$blogArticleId = trimIdFromSlug($slug);
      $blogPosts = Bugz\BlogArticle::where($search, 'LIKE', $slug)->get();

      dd($blogPosts);

      //show the page:
      $viewData = array(
          'metaTitle'         => 'Blog | ' . config('app.name'),
          'metaSectionJs'     => 'public-blog-single',
          'metaSectionParent' => 'public-blog-single',
          'metaSectionUrl'    => '/blog/{slug}'
      );

      return view('public.blog', compact('viewData', 'blogPosts'));

    }
));
```

In my blog people can either filter blog posts by Archives, Category or Search.

Deepening on what they searched for, I change the the $search variable to a column in the database table. The slug then is the string which I'm searching for.

If I click on "October 2015" then the URL is:
**/blog/archives/2015-10**

In the database the records are stored as **2015-10-31 11:32:00**

However the query is not returning anything even though the published_at column contains records that contain the string I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a minor thing, you need to add the wildcard to your query:

```
  $blogPosts = Bugz\BlogArticle::where($search, 'LIKE', $slug.'%')->get();
```

So this will look for dates starting with 2015-10.

Comment: Side note: This will of course also affect the search by category and title, so if you have two categories sharing a prefix, like "Flow" and "Flower", you'll find both if you select the category "Flow".